# How to multiply value in datagridview column by a textbox in a button click and get output same column c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to multiply value in Datagrid view by a text box in a button click. 
Example
Value in Datagrid view column (Cell [10]) Column Index ["Deposit"] Values 1000, 2000, 300.75 
I need to input the number of months into the textbox and click the button and hope a result: Example: textbox value is 2 after button click / Deposit value should be 2000, 4000, 601.50
Note: I need to change these values to the same column ["Deposit"] Cell [10], not another column

See below code i have tried to get output, but it was not working, can anyone help me for this?

```
var xs = listA.Exists(listB);
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
       double val1, val2, tot;
       double.TryParse(Txtmonth.Text, out val1);
       val2 = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value);
       tot = (val1 * val2);

     }
```

Comment: You are not appending the value back to the `cell` add `DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = tot;` after the `tot` is calculated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
     {
       double val1, val2;
       double.TryParse(Txtmonth.Text, out val1);
       DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value) * val1;
     }
```

Comment: Can you help me for this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789710/get-minimum-value-in-datagridview-column-with-removing-duplicate-value-in-other