# Get minimum value in DataGridView column with removing duplicate value in other column after comparing c# windows application

Tags: c#

I used below code to remove duplicate value in DataGridView cell[0], however i want to remove 
            duplicate value in cell[0] after getting minimum value in cell[11].[image]

```
for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; currentRow++)
         {
             DataGridViewRow rowToCompare = DataGridView1.Rows[currentRow];

             for (int otherRow = currentRow + 1; otherRow < DataGridView1.Rows.Count; otherRow++)
             {
                 DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.Rows[otherRow];

                 bool duplicateRow = true;

                 for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < row.Cells.Count; cellIndex++)
                 {
                     if (!rowToCompare.Cells[0].Value.Equals(row.Cells[0].Value))
                     {
                         duplicateRow = false;
                         break;
                     }
                 }

                 if (duplicateRow)
                 {

                     DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
                     otherRow--;
                 }

             }
         }
```

Comment: Please answer for this...

Comment: @Charles May, can you help me for this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789710/get-minimum-value-in-datagridview-column-with-removing-duplicate-value-in-other